# Python: Require user to input a number, and if 1 is selected it is to print out text, otherwise it should quit the program

Tags: python, input

I'm new to Python and I'm having some trouble getting this program to print out specific text given some user input. This is my attempt:

```
import pandas_datareader as pdr
import datetime 
import pandas as pd

print("\n---------------------------------------------------\n")
print("Stock Report Menu Options")
print("\n---------------------------------------------------\n")

print("1. Report changes for a stock ")
print("2. Quit")
  
answer = input()
while answer != 2:
    if answer == 1:
        print("Please enter the stock option:")
        stockPick = input()
    else:
        break
```

What keeps happening is it'll show me the first 5 printed text lines but then when it prompts to enter an input, it just exits the program (which should only happen if "2" is entered) without giving me the "Please enter the stock option:" text. I'm not sure why this is happening, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Convert user input to `int`: `answer = int(input())`

Comment: Yes, convert user input to `int`. And I'd like to suggest the assignment expression if you are using python>=3.8. It will make your code more consistent: `while (answer := int(input("Please enter the stock option: "))) != 2:`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that:
if input = 1 : "Please enter the stock option:" will be printed.
if imput = 2: Loop will not be executed and nothing will be printed.
if input != 1 and !=2: Loop will be executed once and since the else statement is break it terminates the programme.